# Python, Selenium | Can't Click Test Here

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

[image]

Hello, I am trying to click the button 'Test Here' using selenium in Python via chrome. I have no clue what it is not working. My code is shared below...

`driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Test Here')]").click()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click the button and not the span.

Add /parent::button would fix your xpath.

Comment: I'm sorry, very new to using selenium. Could you give me an exact example?

Comment: Oh just copy it and put it at the end of your xpath. It moves up 1 level to the button tag.

Comment: //span[.='Test Here']/parent::button

Comment: Like the above.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [`find_element_by_link_text`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-hyperlinks-by-link-text) method, like this:

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text("Test Here").click()
```

Comment: This is the error that I got.... :( selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"Test Here}
  (Session info: chrome=88.0.4324.150)

Comment: @ghost Try adding the line `"driver.implicitly_wait(5)"` before the `"driver.find_element_by_link_text("Test Here").click()"` line.